# Python: try-catch with multiple excepts with almost identical code

Tags: python, try-catch, except

I have somthing similar in my code below, where I have multiple except statements and all of them have to execute the someCleanUpCode() function. I was wondering if there is a shorter way to do it. Like a block that is only being executed when there was an exception. I can't use the finally block because that's also being executed when the try doesn't raise an error. And I only need to execute the someCleanUpCode() when there was an error. I first want to print the error and after that, run the someCleanUpCode()

```
try:
  dangerousCode()

except CalledProcessError:
  print "There was an error without a message"
  someCleanUpCode()
except Exception as e:
  print "There was an error: " +repr(e)
  someCleanUpCode()
```

Comment: I'm not aware of any other way to do this. I think the current code is fine - it makes it clear that `someCleanUpCode` is called in every error case.

Comment: Okay, I'll stick to that code ;)

Comment: Assuming the dangerous code is always a function, and you have lots of them, you might want to wrap it with an @foo wrapper that adds the try/except routine whenever the function is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `CalledProcessorError` subclasses `Exception` (which should be the case):

```
try:
   dangerous_code()
except Exception as e:
   print "There was an error %s" % ("without an error" if isinstance(e, CalledProcessError) else repr(e))
   some_cleanup_code()
```

or if you have more to do:

```
try:
   dangerous_code()
except Exception as e:
       try:
   dangerous_code()
except Exception as e:
   if isinstance(e, CalledProcessError):
       print "There was an error without a message"
   else:
       print "There was an error: " +repr(e)
   some_cleanup_code()
```

Comment: I see, you can do it like this. But this can become very messy when I've got more than two excepts :). But thanks for this code.

Comment: Yes if you have half a dozen except clauses each with it's own specific stuff, your current structure is possibly cleaner... but it's not DRY.

Answer (score 1):

are you looking for something like this?

```
try:
    1/0
except (ValueError, ZeroDivisionError) as e:
    print e
    # add some cleanup code here


>>>integer division or modulo by zero
```

This catches multiple exceptions

Comment: But the problem is that only a part of the code is shared. Not the entire code is the same.